saturated measure Folland exercise 1.3.16c trouble with a helpful Lemma proof
I'm solving Folland's Real Analysis' exercise 16 of session 1.3 and found some trouble. I found this question and have been able to follow the top answer, but there's a part that doesn't present much proof, so I decided to try and prove for myself. I wanted to check my attempt at a solution.
Question 16.c revolves around a semifinite measure $\mu$ and the function $\underline{\mu} \colon \mathcal{L} \to [0,\infty],$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the set of locally measureable sets of $X$, defined by
\begin{equation}
\underline{\mu}(E) = \sup\left\{ \mu(A) \,:\, A \in \mathcal{M},\, A \subseteq E \right\}.
\end{equation}
The part where I got stumped is in the proof of the second case of the lemma

Lemma: Suppose $\mu$ is a semifinite measure on $(X,\mathcal{M}).$ For all $E \in \mathcal{L}$, $$\underline{\mu}(E) = \sup\left\{ \mu(A) \,:\, A \in \mathcal{M},\, A \subseteq E,\, \mu(A) < \infty \right\},$$

which the top answer uses. Especifically in the second case, for when there exists $A_0 \in \mathcal{M}$, $A_0 \subseteq E$ such that $\mu(A) = \infty$. Here's my attempt.
Proof - Let $(X, \mathcal{M})$ be a measureable space and $\mu$ be a semifinite measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$. Let $E$ be a locally measureable space and suppose that there exists $A_0$ measureable set such that $A_0 \subseteq E$ and $\mu(A_0) = \infty$. Then, $\mu(E) = \infty$.
Since $\mu$ is semifinite, there exists a measureable subset $A_1 \subseteq A_0$ such that $0 < \mu(A_1) < \infty$. Now, consider the set $A_0 \setminus A_1.$ From the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$, $\mu\left(A_0\setminus A_1\right) = \infty$ and, since $\mu$ is semifinite, there exists a measureable set $A_2 \subseteq A_0 \setminus A_1$ such that $0 <\mu(A_2)<\infty$. Thus, recursively, we can define a sequence $\left(A_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ by choosing $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_{0}\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j$ with finite measure. From construction, the $A_n$ are disjoint, and so, defining
\begin{equation}
\label{SN}
S_N = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(A_n).
\end{equation}
Since $S_N$ is the measure of a finite union of finite sets (and a finite sum of finite numbers), it is finite for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.
If $\lim_{N\to \infty}S_N = \infty$, then for all $R \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \geq N$, $S_k > R$ and as such we can always find a set of finite measure whose measure is greater than whatever real number is given, so we can conclude that $\sup\left\{ \mu(A) \,:\, A \in \mathcal{M},\, A \subseteq A_0,\, \mu(A) < \infty\right\} = \infty.$
I believe I should be able to prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N = \infty$, but I don't know if I'm going about it in a useful way (or even if my solution up to now is correct). If it wasn't the case, say $S_N \to S \in (0,\infty)$ ($S$ cannot be $0$ since, for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $S_N$ is the sum of numbers that are strictly greater than $0$), then $A_0 \setminus S$ would be a set of infinite measure. Since all $A_n$ are disjoint, the function $n \mapsto A_n$ is a bijection, so from $\mu$ being semifinite we can find $$B_1 \subseteq A_0 \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$ such that $0 < \mu(B_1)< \infty$, so we can conclude there is a non-countable amount of disjoint sets of finite measure. The more useful definition of $S_N$ is in the first equality of its definition, since it's the measure of the first $N$ sets of finite measure of the sequence (and thus a set of finite measure itself), but if, say, we define a non-countable index set $I$ such that for all $i \in I$, $A_i$ is a finite set and all $A_i$ are disjoint, then
$$
\sum_{i \in I}\mu(A_i)
$$
would diverge, but since measures are $\sigma$-additive, I can't really equate that to $S_N$, since it's not a countable union.

I don't believe based on your definition that it's necessary for $\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N = \infty$ since the size of the sets $A_n$ may be getting rapidly smaller. I think you have the general idea, but you'll need to control the size of the sets. Let's focus on showing that if $$\sup\left\{ \mu(A) \,:\, A \in \mathcal{M},\, A \subseteq E \right\} = \infty $$ then $$\sup\left\{ \mu(A) \,:\, A \in \mathcal{M},\, A \subseteq E, \mu(A) < \infty \right\} = \infty $$ as well, (since the finite case is obvious). The only way they could be not equal if there is a measurable $A_0 \subseteq E $ where $\mu(A_0) = \infty$, so (like you have done) we'll assume that such a set exists. Now further suppose toward a contradiction that $$\sup\left\{ \mu(A) \,:\, A \in \mathcal{M},\, A \subseteq E, \mu(A) < \infty \right\} = L < \infty. \tag{*}$$ (The supremum $L$ must be greater than zero by semi-finiteness, so we'll assume that $L>0$). Set $A_n\subseteq E$ to be a measurable set with $$\mu(A_n) \geq L (1- 1/n)$$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ Then we have that $$ L(1-1/n) \leq \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \right) \leq L $$ where the right-hand inequality follows from our earlier assumption (*). Thus $A_\infty = \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ is a measurable subset of $E$ with $\mu(A_\infty) = L$. By semi-finiteness, we have a set $B\subset A_0 \setminus A_\infty$ with positive measure. But then $$\mu(B \cup A_\infty) > L,$$ which is contradiction of (*), and we are done.

Thank you! Just to be sure, in the left-hand side of the second-to-last inequality, you are using the measure's monotonicity to state $L(1-1/n) \leq \mu(A_n) \leq \mu(A_\infty)$, correct? Also, and this isn't really a concern but curiosity, do you think my proof that there is a non-countable amount of disjoint, finite-measure sets in $A_0$ is correct?

@yirgoso (1) Sort of, yeah. Monotonicity was used in the inequality $L(1-1/n) \leq \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \right)$. That $\mu(A_\infty) = L$, I was thinking about continuity of measure, but monotonicity could give you the same thing I think. (2) I don't think your proof is correct. The step between finding $B_1$ and that there are uncountably many sets doesn't really hold. The collection $A_n$ wasn't assumed to be all sets of finite measure, so showing that there is another set wouldn't imply that there is uncountably many such sets.

Maybe I didn't understand point (1). Yes I'm using monotonicity in the second-to-last inequality.
